# What is the proper way to refresh data on screen when using Cocoa and C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am making an app for OS X using Cocoa for the graphical interface. But my main algorithm was made in C++. The interface just shows some values of the algorithm in NSTextFields and NSLevelIndicator.

The screen needs to be refresh with the data from the algorithm in real time.

What i did is a NSThread that reads the data from the algorithm and put on screen. But I don't think that it's the proper way.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without more detail about the specifics of the code you're righting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you should only update the GUI from the main thread.  You can submit some work to the main thread with code like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [myTextField setStringValue:@"a new string"];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you could go with:

- Use a repeating NSTimer on the main thread to grab values from your algorithm and then display them
- Use dispatch_async from the algorithm as Ken Thomases wrote
- Use performSelectorOnMainThread from the algorithm
- Have the algorithm post notifications to NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Posting notifications does nothing to help with threading issues. Notifications are received on the same thread where they are posted. Edit: Well, you can add an observer with the main `NSOperationQueue` using `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`, but that's more about the observer and not the code posting the notification.